# Beego orm not equal to operator

Tags: go, beego

Is there a way to use not equal to operator (`!= OR <>`) in Beego orm? i don't want to use the `WHERE IN` condition because it means that i have to make a query to another table first. is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The [docs](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/query.md#exclude) would suggest that you'd use `Exclude()` for that, no?

Comment: Ohh yes, i was thinking that exclude return a `NOT IN` condition. which i think i miss understood the docs.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you've figured it out (with or without someone else's help). I don't have any Beego things set up to verify my guesswork so you're welcome answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for someone that might misunderstood the `Exclude()` method in [Beego](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/query.md#exclude) Docs as i did. This does not specific return a `NOT IN` condition it can also be use as `not equal to` operator (`!=` OR `<>`).